# Cytoscape.js Preset Layout Documentation

Tags: javascript, dictionary, cytoscape.js

I have a cytoscape.js graph that renders. I'm interested in leveraging the preset layout to place the nodes. The cytoscape.js documentation shows the following for the preset layout:

```
var options = {
  name: 'preset',
  positions: undefined, // map of (node id) => (position obj); or function(node){ return somPos; }
  zoom: undefined, // the zoom level to set (prob want fit = false if set)
  pan: undefined, // the pan level to set (prob want fit = false if set)
  fit: true, // whether to fit to viewport
  padding: 30, // padding on fit
  animate: false, // whether to transition the node positions
  animationDuration: 500, // duration of animation in ms if enabled
  animationEasing: undefined, // easing of animation if enabled
  ready: undefined, // callback on layoutready
  stop: undefined // callback on layoutstop
};
```

Can some one help me understand or give an example of what the documentation means when it says the following

```
// map of (node id) => (position obj); or function(node){ return somPos; }
```

I store all the nodes in a MySQL database table with the following columns

`id, origin, destination, x position, y position`

Does the cytoscape.js positions take a dictionary that looks like this:

`{'id': 1, {'x':10, 'y':45}}, {'id': 2, {'x':21, 'y':32}}` etc?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This means when the `positions` is set as `undefined` you need to create a function to get the positions of each node.

For example:

```js
 cy.nodes().forEach(function(n){
    var x = n.data("x");
    var y = n.data("y");
 });
```

This *should* return your node position.

**EDIT**

You can set the node position when you are creating it. For example:

```js
  var elements;
  elements: [{"data":{"id":"yourID","name":"name"},"position"{"x":"0.0","y":"0.0"}}];
```

For more, see [this](https://gist.github.com/maxkfranz/2ebdc40f1c2540de6cf0http://) Demo on Cytoscape js site. Here they set the position manually.

Comment: Thank you for the reply by the original question is more about how to set the positions than to get them.

Comment: If you define positions in the element JSON like @MFigueredo's example, then you don't have to do anything more than specify `layout: { name: 'preset' }` at init.  By default the preset layout does nothing and just uses the positions already defined.  The other features of the layout are for if you want to manually specify new positions, use animations, etc.